# Need to read max date folder files In pyspark - Databricks

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

I have many folders in which I have to read max date folder files. Consider I have two folders xyz and abc both have months and date folder inside them.
From xyz I have to read month 5 which is maxed in month folder and 7 which is maxed in date folder.

[image: Folder Structure]

I have tried below code bu its not working.

[image: Tried codes]

Answer (score 2):

Here is one way using Hadoop FS API method [`listStatus`](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.8.2/api/org/apache/hadoop/fs/FileSystem.html#listStatus(org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path)). First, list all the files under `xyz` folder and get the max folder using the name. And then do the same to get the max day folder:

```
Path = sc._gateway.jvm.org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path

folder_path = Path("/path/to/xyz")
fs = folder_path.getFileSystem(sc._jsc.hadoopConfiguration())

# list all subfolders and returns path + name
month_folders = [(f.getPath().toString(), f.getPath().getName()) for f in fs.listStatus(folder_path) if f.isDir()]
# filter by name to get the max
max_month_folder = max(month_folders, key=lambda x: x[1])[0]

# Now list day subfolders as for month
day_folder = [(f.getPath().toString(), f.getPath().getName()) for f in fs.listStatus(Path(max_month_folder)) if f.isDir()]
max_day_folder = max(day_folder, key=lambda x: x[1])[0]

# read max folder
spark.read.csv(max_day_folder)
```

Answer (score 1):

I think this question is not made for a pyspark solution as you have not a partitioned folder structure rather it is more a general python question. You are looking for the max in the folders on a databricks filesystem `dbfs`.

As the first answer says you can use the hadoop filesystem api.

Another way that I prefer more as it is more flexible in handling local paths and dbfs paths is to change the dbfs path to local path. Imagine you are working locally and in databricks. The paths on how you gonna access the data are different. But you want to test locally with your IDE first the above solution might not work until you gonna setup hive on your local machine.

What you can do is to replace first the dbfs path into a normal file system path and working with the python libraries.

```
from pathlib import Path
from typing import Union
import os

def get_local_path(path: Union[str, Path, os.path]) -> str:
    """
    Transforms a potential dbfs path to a
    path accessible by standard file system operations

    :param path: Path to transform to local path
    :return: The local path
    """
    return str(path).replace("dbfs:", "/dbfs")


dbfs_path = "dbfs:/path_to/xyz"
local_path = get_local_path(dbfs_path)
```

The above function replaces i.e. `dbfs:/path_to/xyz` by `/dbfs/path_to/xyz`.

From now on you can use the python `os` or `pathlib` functionalities.

```
def find_max_in_folders(path) -> str:
    """
    Finds the maximum folder number.
    
    :param path: The path of the folders.
    :return: The max number in the folders.
    """
    dirs = [int(dir_name) for dir_name in os.listdir(path) if os.path.is_dir(os.path.join(path, dir_name))]
    the_max = max(dirs)

    return the_max 

max_month = find_max_in_folders(local_path)
month_path = os.path.join(local_path, f"month/{max_month}")
max_day = find_max_in_folders(month_path)

print(f"max_month: {max_month}"
print(f"max_day: {max_day}"
```

Also if the data would be partitioned correctly like `month=...` and `day=...`then it is also not a good idea to load the data by loading from the root path. If forces spark to read and scan first all underlying data. If your folders are getting bigger and the data under the hood is also big then this would be the worst idea dealing with the above problem.

In order someone jumps over this answer and looking for a partition pruning solution it is better to go and scan the filesystem on your own (like the above answer) if you are not working with watermarks and you are only looking for the latest data dumps.